# PHP API offset Pagination

Tags: php, arrays, json, pagination

I have the following code but I am not sure how to loop and offset records to get the next 20 records using the same function loop.

gameid is zero on the first call and on the second call the gameid is 21.

```
$result = new ArrayObject();

  
$count = 0;
foreach($response as &$game) {
    
    $game  = get_object_vars($game);
         
    if ($game['gameType'] == $gametype )
    {   
        $result->append(array($game['gameName'], $game['gameType']));
        if ($count == $gameid+19) break;
        $count ++ ;
        
    }       
    
}
```

Thank You

Comment: That would depend on what you're planning on doing with `$response` after the loop completes. You're populating a `$result`, which to me suggests that your `$response` would ideally be left in tact, yet you're converting every element of it. Why? If you just need to paginate, then you could use something like `foreach(array_slice($response, $offset, $limit) as $game) {`.

Comment: Thank you @RoAchterberg but I can't use this because I want to filter by game type 
$game['gameType'] == $gametype

Comment: Then why not simply filter `$response` first on that condition, so you're paginating an array of your specific game type elements only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use the concept of page size and page index.

In you case seem like you want page size of 20. Sending second request with `gameid` mean you want page size 20 and page index 1 (instead of 0).

So consider code like this:

```
$count = 0;
$pageSize = 20; // this can be const or come as param
$pageIndex = 0; // this should be as params
foreach($response as &$game) {

    $game  = get_object_vars($game);
     
    if ($game['gameType'] == $gametype ) {
        $count++ ;
        if ($count > ($pageSize * $pageIndex))
            $result->append(array($game['gameName'], $game['gameType']));
        // if you over the request chunk break
        if ($count > ($pageSize * ($pageIndex + 1)) break; 
        
    
    }       

}
```